# How can I use pool.starmap and zip to combine and pass an entire list with a single element

Tags: python, list, zip, pool

I thought about a interesting question and I hope somebody can help me solve this!
I want to use multiprocessing, so I choose to use pool.starmap(myfunction,zip([1,2,3,4,5],['a','b','c','d','e'])) in order to pass multi arguments. I want to combine the entire list [1,2,3,4,5] with the every single element in the second list such as

```
([1,2,3,4,5],'a'),([1,2,3,4,5],'b').....
```

instead of only combining the single element in the lists such as

```
(1,'a'),(2,'b')
```

I know how to do it in a stupid way which is multiply the list by 5

```
new_list=[1,2,3,4,5]*5
```

and then zip the new_list with the second list

I'm now wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comment I assume you are looking for `itertools.repeat`:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing

def combine(val, char):
    return f'{val}{char}'

vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
combs = pool.starmap(combine, zip(itertools.repeat(vals, 5), chars))

print(combs)
```

This has a smaller memory footprint than the naive approach, which is simply

```
combs = pool.starmap(combine, zip([vals]*5, chars))
```

If you instead want to generate all combinations of the `vals`and the `chars` elements, you could use `itertools.product` (which is what I first assumed you wanted):

```
combs = pool.starmap(combine, itertools.product(vals, chars))
```

As a sidenote; `itertools` also contain a `starmap` function that works more or less the same as the `multiprocessing` one, except for executing all calls in one process, in order. This, however, can not take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: Oh no I tried the product  function but that's not what I want, I want to combine the entire list "vals" with every single element in "chars" instead of combining every single element in "vals" with "chars"

Comment: OK, but then what is wrong with your "naive" approach where you just mutliply the list by 5? That will do the trick, right?

Comment: Oh yeah, there's nothing wrong but I just want to know if there is a pythonic way to do this lol

Comment: I would say that it would be Pythonic enough to multiply the list as you suggest. This is a somewhat special use case and it is hard to give really strict guide lines on exactly when something stops being "Pythonic".